# Brooks' Theorem and connectedness

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I wonder if

> **Brooks' Theorem:** Every connected simple graph $G$ which is not complete and not an odd cycle has chromatic number $\chi(G)$ at most equal to $G$'s maximal degree $\Delta(G)$.

really needs the hypothesis that $G$ is connected. After all, the theorem may be applied to a connected component of $G$ whose chromatic number is $\chi(G)$ and whose maximal degree is necessarily at most $\Delta(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right ; you can apply the brook's thm on non-connected components of a graph G. However, there's no real point to it since you would be just considering the components as basically two individual graphs (which just comes back to applying the theorem on a connected graph). In conclusion useless case to consider, Brook's theorem's value is in the connected graphs.

For more details, the paper Brooks' theorem and beyond by Cranston and Rabern is a good source.